# T-SQL find the most recent customer record with no subsequent appts booked

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have Customer Appt table:

```
ID PK
CID FK
ApptDate
Status ( it could be; awaiting response, cancelled, did not attend, attended)
```

Customer Table:

```
CID PK
Name
SUrname
address etc.
```

every customer have multiple appointments booked and my task is finding the last appointment where status is not Attended And customer have not had any subsequent appts booked..

i've tried subquery but didn't work..also tried this:

```
select ID, CID, max(ApptDate)
from customer_appts
where status!= 'Attended'
```

this is not checking if there wasnt any subsequent appts booked.. I think i need to use if statement or nested.. if any one could direct me i'd be grateful

**UPDATE:** 
Example: appt records for customer ID: 20 -- it should return last record date 23/20/20-- No subsequent appts booked after that date and status is not attended

```
ID  CID Appt Date   Status
1   20  27/01/20    Not Attended
2   20  30/01/20    Attended
3   20  23/02/20    cancelled
```

**MORE EXAMPLES**

```
ID  CID Appt Date   Status
1   30  27/01/20    Not Attended
2   30  30/01/20    Cancelled
3   30  23/02/20    Attended
```

for Customer 30 it should NOT return any records as after the 'Cancelled' appts we booked them an appointment and status is 'Attended'

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, I assume you want the last appointment PER CUSTOMER, not just the last appointment.

Comment: yes, per customer

Comment: You said you want customers (actually appointments?) for any customer that has an appointment with status 'not attended' and no following appointments. But customer 20 does have following appointments. Your goal is not clear and a single, tiny data sample is not enough to illustrate.

Comment: Last appointment for customer 20 status is 'Cancelled' and no other appointments booked. I apologise if its not very clear

Comment: @Jane Check my answer, I think this is what you want.

Comment: okay .. i will try it now. cheers.

Comment: @Jane Unless the `id` can't be used for ordering it should work. If it can't then you only have to use the `appt_date` column instead of the `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to find out which client didn't have an appointment since the last time they missed one. Note that I've assumed `id` was an identity column and as good as the date for ordering.

Here's one way of doing it...

```
SELECT *
FROM customer_appts a
WHERE
  status <> 'Attended'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM customer_appts
    WHERE cid = a.cid AND id > a.id
  )
```

Here's another...

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY id DESC) AS ordering
  FROM customer_appts
) a
WHERE 
  a.ordering = 1
  AND status <> 'Attended'
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/388442/1)

Comment: IT WORKED (the 2nd one).. thank you so so much! I will try and understand how you've written your query. I would be grateful if you send me useful links to read. Cheers xx

Comment: The first one should be working too, unless I've missed an edge case. Could you give me an example where it's not working? As for the second query, `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY cid ORDER BY id DESC)` will give you an appointment ordering per customer in descending order. Once you have that you only need to check if the last appointment of a given customer (`a.ordering = 1`) wasn't attended (`status <> 'Attended'`).

Comment: The first query does the same thing. It finds the last unattended appointment per customer `(MAX(id) … GROUP BY cid)` and makes sure it's not followed by any other appointment entries.

Comment: Updated the first one, we dont actually have to check for the MAX given it's the MAX if there's no events following it already...

Answer (score 0):

> my task is finding the last appointment where status is not Attended.

I think you want:

```
select a.*
from customer_appts a
where a.id = (select top (1) a2.id
              from customer_appts a2
              where a2.cid = a.cid and
                    a2.status <> 'Attended'
              order by a2.ApptDate desc
             );
```

Comment: This is not returning last appointment with No subsequent appts booked.,. Its returning last appt date when status <> 'attended'

Comment: @Jane . . . That is *exactly* what this question is asking for:  "my task is finding the last appointment where status is not Attended."  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Comment: No that wasn't! you took part of the question however the title of this question is super clear.. if u can't help that's absolutely fine..cheers

Comment: @GordonLinoff Quick question since you seem very knowledgeable in SQL. Wouldn't a `MAX GROUP BY` be more efficient given it's not correlated as opposed to `TOP 1 ORDER BY WHERE`...?

Comment: @plalx . . . No, generally not.  I would expect this to have the best performance with the right indexes.  It is also guaranteed to return one row.